# Stripe webhooks don't fire locally NEXT JS

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, next.js13

Having trouble getting the local testing of Stripe Webhooks working. Here is a Next JS routehandler api endpoint that should listen to Stripe webhooks. I have confirmed that the endpoint is running by curling it via the terminal and can get a log in the terminal. If I do ex 'Webhook signature verification failed.' as logged. If I do
`stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:3000/api/webhooks` it starts to listen to my local endpoint but then for example
`stripe trigger customer.subscription.created` or other triggered events do not give any console logging at all nor event log in the Stripe dashboard. 
 app/api/webhooks/route.ts 
stripe version 1.17.1 
next: "13.4.4"

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { stripe } from '@utils/stripe';
import Stripe from 'stripe';

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    console.log('Endpoint hit');
    const rawBody = await request.text();
    console.log('RAW BODY:', rawBody);
    const sig = request.headers.get('stripe-signature') || '';
    console.log('SIGNATURE', sig);

    let event: Stripe.Event;
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        rawBody,
        sig,
        'whsec_5e..'
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(
        `Webhook signature verification failed.`
      );
      return NextResponse.json({ received: false }, { status: 400 });
    }

    switch (event.type) {
      case 'customer.subscription.created':
        console.log('case sub created');
        break;
      case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        console.log('PAYMENT INTENT EVENT');
        break;

      default:
        // Unexpected event type
        console.warn(`Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
        break;
    }

    // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
    return NextResponse.json({ received: true }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error in POST function:', e);
    return NextResponse.json({ received: false }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Comment: try chatting with the devs on the stripe discord channel

Comment: What is the CLI log saying? Does it 404 or something else when trying to forward? Are you able to POST to your webhook endpoint manually via curl/postman? I suspect this is a routing issue with the endpoint.

Comment: @NolanH yes curl works but nothing when trying stripe triggering.

Comment: Do you see the event in the `stripe listen` logs? Can you share that output in your question?

Comment: So turns out I am such an idiot, I tried running the trigger command in the same terminal I was running the listener. Thanks guys and the Stripe discord chat star codename_duchess for the help. I will rest now

Answer (score 0):

opened one more terminal and triggered the `stripe trigger customer.subscription.created` from there